# How does Facebook track Like or other activities on my site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Addthis.com's service to add facebook 'like' button onto my site. 
Now I want to manually add some facebook social plugins to my site: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

As I see, some plugins require to enter 'app_id', but I didn't specify my 'app_id' for Addthis.com's buttons, so I would like to ask how does facebook track those 'like' or other activities on my site??

For example, if a user clicked 'like' on Addthis.com's button on my site, would this user appear in the "Like Box" and "Facepile" plugins that I manually added to my site??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AddThis**

When using `AddThis`, the app itself, gets the current page that is `liked` or the specified Facebook page. When you are referring to the `app_id` for `AddThis`, it is their own id that allows you to log into http://www.addthis.com and access their custom statistics page.

**Facebook**

When using the `Facebook` like button or other plugins, `Facebook` records the number of times someone has pressed the button. It also includes `shares` and `reposts` in this number. Using the `Facebook API` you would be able to seperate the numbers (whether `like` or `share`) if desired.

**Facebook API**

In order to access the information recorded by `Facebook` you must register and app with them and that will give you a Facebook `app_id`. This can then be used in any of their plugins.

**Overall**

Since the `AddThis` app transfers the information to `Facebook`, `Facebook` will display your like and share count in any of its plugins.

Comment: I don't understand, you said I need app_id to access information recorded by facebook, but addthis are using their own app_id, so does it mean I need to enter addthis's app_id when using facebook plugins??

Comment: no. When you are using Facebooks API you need to use an app_id to get any information. When it comes to AddThis, they have additional statistics on their website. In order for them to specifically track everytime a person clicks on an AddThis button on your website, they use an id (which allows them to distinguish and track your data). These are two seperate `app_id`s. For Facebook go to their `developers` sections and get an `app_id`. There are also plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: I didn't enter any app_id on addthis, so how does facebook track those 'like' and reported them back to those plugins? FB recorded the liked URL on their server??

Comment: when you dont enter anything on AddThis is does its normal function => tells Facebook you liked the page and done! It is the same as just a normal `Facebook like plugin`. So to answer your question, yes it reports to Facebook everytime you click like and then loads the `like count` from `Facebook` everytime the page is reloaded

Comment: thanks, one more thing, as I see, those like button would report the like count for that specific page only. If I add a 'like box' or other plugins, would I make it to report ALL the like counts from my site??

Comment: does this answer your question? If so, don't forget to accept :)

Comment: no. a like box will display the people who like your `Facebook page`. When someone likes a link on your site with `AddThis` is automatically takes the specific URL (with params) of the page and adds a like to it. In order to get your general site to be liked *use the `Facebook` like button and specify your URL w/o params* Example : `www.mydomain.com` **NOT** `www.mydomain.com/contact?hello` etc..

Comment: I see, but if I specify 'www.mydomain.com', then 'www.mydomain.com' would show up in the newsfeed instead of the exact URL, right?? If yes, this would be a shortcoming for sharing..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14997/discussion-between-mlishn-and-rrn)